# Google closure compiler reports JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE errors on javascript keywords

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to minimize my js code using the resources-optimizer-maven-plugin which underneath is using the google closure-compiler.

My problem is that, after the aggregation is completed, google closure-compiler reports a bunch of  JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE  errors, killing the build.

Any idea why I get this type of error?

3rd party libraries are excluded from the plugin. Only my code is being processed.

PS: this code runs properly on Chrome, Edge, etc.

My .pom plugin configuration is :

```
<plugin>
              <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
              <artifactId>resources-optimizer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.5.6</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>optimize</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>optimize</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                <compilationLevel>SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS</compilationLevel>
                <warningLevel>VERBOSE</warningLevel>
                <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
                <suffix>-min</suffix>
                <useDataUri>false</useDataUri>
                <languageIn>ECMASCRIPT_2017</languageIn>
                <languageOut>ECMASCRIPT_2017</languageOut>
                <resourcesSets>
                  <resourcesSet>
                    <inputDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/p/js</inputDir>
                    <includes>
                      <include>*.js</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>./lib/*.js</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <aggregations>
                        <aggregation>
                          <withoutCompress>false</withoutCompress>
                          <outputFile>
                            ${project.build.directory}/webapp/resources/scripts.js
                          </outputFile>
                        </aggregation>
                      </aggregations>
                  </resourcesSet>
                  <resourcesSet>
                    <inputDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/static/p</inputDir>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*.css</include>
                    </includes>
                    <aggregations>
                      <aggregation>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/webapp/resources/min.css</outputFile>
                      </aggregation>
                    </aggregations>
                  </resourcesSet>
                </resourcesSets>
              </configuration>        
            </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

The errors returned:

```
INFO] --- resources-optimizer-maven-plugin:2.5.6:optimize (optimize) @ middleware ---
[INFO] Optimize JS file alerts.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file barcodeReader.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file camera.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file charts.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file contact.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file enLocalization.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file exchange.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file filter.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file friends.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file image.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file loading.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file locales.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file location.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file mainView.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file manageAds.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file manageCredits.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file maps.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file mwutils.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file onlineLocation.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file pagination.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file plans.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file policy.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file product.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file productEdit.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file pub.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file ratings.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file reports.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file roLocalization.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file search.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file searchSelect.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file settings.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file share.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file shoppingCart.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file store.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file storeEdit.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file systemAlerts.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file taxes.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file theme.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file translate.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file urlutils.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file user.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file utils.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file validation.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file veil.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file version.js ...
[INFO] Optimize JS file versionHistory.js ...
May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:11:19: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable document is undeclared
  11| var alertElement = document.getElementById(ALERT_ID);
                         ^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:34:13: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable setTimeout is undeclared
  34|   timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:42:2: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable clearTimeout is undeclared
  42|           clearTimeout(timeoutId);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:182:5: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable navigator is undeclared
  182|  if (navigator.mediaDevices && typeof navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === 'function') {
            ^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:184:3: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Quagga is undeclared
  184|    Quagga.init({
          ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:207:11: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable console is undeclared
  207|            console.log(err);
                  ^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:219:44: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable parseInt is undeclared
  219|                  drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
                                                   ^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:284:29: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Object is undeclared
  284|          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(stack)) {
                                           ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:483:19: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Math is undeclared
  483|          let newHeight =  Math.floor(dim);
                                 ^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:614:31: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Date is undeclared
  614|                          dataObject.push({date: new Date(response.content[i].creationTime), value: response.content[i].basePrice, currency: response.content[i].currency, isLast: false});
                                                           ^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:644:11: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable d3 is undeclared
  644|     return d3.axisBottom(x)
                  ^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:704:17: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable isNaN is undeclared
  704|          .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
                               ^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:1323:1: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable window is undeclared
  1323| ;window['en'] = {
         ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:3488:11: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Stripe is undeclared
  3488|                 stripe = Stripe(settings.stripePublicKey);
                                 ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:3638:27: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable URLSearchParams is undeclared
  3638|   const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:4227:55: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable JSON is undeclared
  4227|                                 <div class="productBrand" onclick='filterOnBrand(${JSON.stringify(response.content.content[i])})'>
                                                                                           ^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:4612:13: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable parseFloat is undeclared
  4612|                 setElement(parseFloat(maxDistance), DISTANCE);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:4707:25: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable encodeURIComponent is undeclared
  4707|                 result += '?filter=' + encodeURIComponent(filter);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:4898:26: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable localStorage is undeclared
  4898|         let storageSortResults = localStorage.getItem(USER_FRIENDS_SORT_FIELD_ID);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:5360:12: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable URL is undeclared
  5360|                 let src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                  ^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:5816:18: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable L is undeclared
  5816|                                 map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(currentLocation.latitude + mapHeight / 2.1, currentLocation.longitude));
                                                      ^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:6203:15: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Promise is undeclared
  6203|     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                       ^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:6566:29: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable av is undeclared
  6566|                 let lv = new av(a,b);
                                     ^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:6582:20: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable google is undeclared
  6582|                         translator = new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE},  TRANSLATE_ICON_ID);
                                                 ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:6946:21: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable FormData is undeclared
  6946|         let multipart = new FormData();
                                    ^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:6951:31: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Blob is undeclared
  6951|         multipart.append('adDTO', new Blob([JSON.stringify(adDTO)], {
                                              ^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:9063:31: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable fetch is undeclared
  9063|         const response = await fetch(url, settings);
                                       ^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:11559:18: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable undefined is undeclared
  11559|        if (getUser() != undefined && getUser().currencies != undefined && getUser().currencies.length > 0) {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:15088:53: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable NaN is undeclared
  15088|        if (page === null || page === undefined || page === NaN || page <0) {
                                                                    ^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:15123:60: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Number is undeclared
  15123|                if (!isValueEmpty(minPrice) && !isValueEmpty(maxPrice) && Number(minPrice) > Number(maxPrice)) {
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:16804:2: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable scannerContainer is undeclared
  16804|                scannerContainer.classList.add('displayNone')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:19383:19: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Array is undeclared
  19383|        let queryParams = Array.from(url.searchParams);
                                  ^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:19594:2: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable history is undeclared
  19594|                history.pushState({}, '', newUrl);
                        ^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:20851:0: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable String is undeclared
  20851| String.prototype.format = function () {
         ^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:21164:30: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable Element is undeclared
  21164|     return element instanceof Element || element instanceof HTMLDocument;  
                                       ^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:21164:60: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable HTMLDocument is undeclared
  21164|     return element instanceof Element || element instanceof HTMLDocument;  
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:21279:2: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable sessionStorage is undeclared
  21279|                sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 37 error(s), 0 warning(s)
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable document is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 11 : 19
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable setTimeout is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 34 : 13
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable clearTimeout is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 42 : 2
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable navigator is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 182 : 5
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Quagga is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 184 : 3
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable console is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 207 : 11
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable parseInt is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 219 : 44
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Object is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 284 : 29
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Math is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 483 : 19
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Date is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 614 : 31
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable d3 is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 644 : 11
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable isNaN is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 704 : 17
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable window is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 1323 : 1
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Stripe is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 3488 : 11
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable URLSearchParams is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 3638 : 27
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable JSON is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 4227 : 55
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable parseFloat is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 4612 : 13
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable encodeURIComponent is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 4707 : 25
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable localStorage is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 4898 : 26
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable URL is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 5360 : 12
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable L is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 5816 : 18
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Promise is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 6203 : 15
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable av is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 6566 : 29
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable google is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 6582 : 20
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable FormData is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 6946 : 21
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Blob is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 6951 : 31
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable fetch is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 9063 : 31
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable undefined is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 11559 : 18
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable NaN is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 15088 : 53
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Number is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 15123 : 60
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable scannerContainer is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 16804 : 2
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Array is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 19383 : 19
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable history is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 19594 : 2
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable String is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 20851 : 0
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable Element is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 21164 : 30
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable HTMLDocument is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 21164 : 60
[ERROR] JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE. variable sessionStorage is undeclared at /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js line 21279 : 2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.157 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-01T14:13:18-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.primefaces.extensions:resources-optimizer-maven-plugin:2.5.6:optimize (optimize) on project middleware: Resources optimization failure: Resources optimization failure. Please fix errors and try again. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Building component completed
```

Answer (score 1):

These aren't keywords, they are specific JavaScript objects, properties, etc. Closure compiler does have a built-in list of many/most such symbols provided by the browser in its default externs list, but somehow this is missing the way you are running the compiler.

When running the compiler from the command line, this could be done deliberately, by specifying `--env CUSTOM`. However, this defaults to `--env BROWSER`, which means that all of the browser objects and properties will be available (see https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options#basic-usage).

It *looks* like the maven plugin you're using could be skipping configuring this at all. This shouldn't be a problem with compilation levels other than ADVANCED, but your example shows that you are specifying SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS - are you sure that's correct?

Note also that excluding third party toolkits from ADVANCED builds means that externs must be provided for them. You can see one such error here:

```
May 01, 2023 2:13:18 P.M. com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: /opt/RD/project-k-middleware/target/webapp/resources/scripts.source.js:644:11: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable d3 is undeclared
  644|     return d3.axisBottom(x)
                  ^^
```

While your project is using d3, and is likely using advanced optimizations, you haven't told the compiler what d3 is, or what methods/types/properties it has. As a result, the compiler can't check if your code is correct or not, and has to assume that this is an error.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure I am specifying SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. The only way to not get the errors is when I'm passing WHITESPACE_ONLY. Before getting to the 3rd party libs, I would like to figure out why the javascript objects are not recognized

Comment: Sorry about that. The rest of the answer still applies - closure needs externs if it is going to get all the types worked out, so either the plugin is missing them, not using them properly, or you haven't configured it correctly. Try another maven plugin for closure, or just call it directly using exec:java or exec:exec?

Comment: I am the author of this Maven Plugin and it works fine. The Google Closure compiler default is already set `this.environment = CompilerOptions.Environment.BROWSER;`

Comment: I posted my working example in the ticket compiling to ECMASCRIPT_2018 just fine: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/resources-optimizer-maven-plugin/issues/117#event-9145018759

Comment: Thanks - any ideas why obvious symbols like `document`, `setTimeout`, `console` would be missing? This question might be better suited for a bug report with a minimal test case...

Comment: @Melloware, you can see these errors in PFE showcase project, if you try building it with `<warningLevel>VERBOSE</warningLevel>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've dropped the plugin for now and used directly the google closure compiler, and managed to get the expected minified output, using this code:

```
 private static String compile(String code) {
        Compiler compiler = new Compiler();

        CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();

        CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);
        options.setBrowserFeaturesetYear(2019);

        SourceFile extern = SourceFile.fromCode("externs.js", "");

        SourceFile input = SourceFile.fromCode("input.js", code);

        compiler.compile(extern, input, options);

        return compiler.toSource();
      }
```

I've noticed though that by just changing the CompilationLevel to ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, I get the exact errors the maven plugin was returning when I was setting the compilation level to SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS. @Melloware I'm not sure what you are doing, but on my side the plugin is not working properly. Anyhow thanks all. I will stick with the google closure compiler for and drop the plugin for now.

This is a js file that fails compilation in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, in case you want to debug it:

```
const ALERT_DURATION = 6000;
const TYPE_ERROR = 'error';
const TYPE_WARNING= 'warning';
const ALERT_ID = 'alert';
const TOAST_ID = 'toast';
const TOAST_MESSAGE_ID = 'toastMessage';
const BOTTOM_ALLERT_ID = 'bottomAlert';
const COOKIES_ACCEPTED_KEY = 'cookiesAccepted'
const REQUEST_ERROR_FIELD = 'requestError';

var timeoutId = null;

const POSITION_TOP = 'top';
const POSITION_CENTER = 'center';

function getAlert(message, type, position) {
    return `
    <div class="${type} ${position}">
        ${message}
    </div>
    `;
}

function showTopAlert(message, type) {
    showDivAlert(message, type, POSITION_TOP);
}

function showDivAlert(message, type, position) {
    cancelTimeout();
    let alertElement = document.getElementById(ALERT_ID);
    alertElement.innerHTML = getAlert(message, type, position);
    enableAlert();
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        disableAlert();
        timeoutId = undefined;
    }, ALERT_DURATION);
}

function cancelTimeout() {
    if (timeoutId != undefined) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = undefined;
    }
}

function showAlert(message, type) {
    alert(message);
}

function enableAlert() {
    let alertElement = document.getElementById(ALERT_ID);
    alertElement.style.display = BLOCK;
}

function disableAlert() {
    let alertElement = document.getElementById(ALERT_ID);
    alertElement.style.display = NONE;
}

function hideRequestErrorField() {
    hideErrorField(REQUEST_ERROR_FIELD);
}

function hideErrorField(id) {
    let requestErrorField = document.getElementById(id);
    requestErrorField.style.display = 'none';
    requestErrorField.innerHTML = '';
}

function showRequestErrorField(message) {
    showErrorField(REQUEST_ERROR_FIELD, message);
}

function showErrorField(id, message) {
    let requestErrorField = document.getElementById(id);
    requestErrorField.innerHTML = message;
    requestErrorField.style.display = 'block';
}

function showDialogAlert(content, className) {
    getDialogContentContainer().innerHTML = ``;
    getDialogContentContainer().style = 'padding-bottom: 0px';
    getDialogContentContainer().innerHTML = content;
    if (!isValueEmpty(className)) {
        getDialogContentContainer().className = className;
    } else {
        getDialogContentContainer().className = '';
    }
    enableVeil();
}

function showDialogLoading() {
    showDialogAlert('');
    getDialogContentContainer().style = "padding: 30px; height: 90px;";
    showLoadingVeil();
}

function showLocationErrorField(message) {
    showErrorField('locationError', message);
}

function hideLocationErrorField() {
    hideErrorField('locationError');
}

function getSomethingWentWrongAlert() {
    return `
    <div class="warningText">
        ${getStr('somethingWentWrong')}
    </div>
    `;
}

function getUserNotLoggedInAlertContent() {
    return `
    <span>${getStr('editLogInRequired').format(getSignInLink())}</>
    `;
}

function showToastError(message) {
    let toast = document.getElementById(TOAST_ID);
    toast.title = message;
    let toastMessage = document.getElementById(TOAST_MESSAGE_ID);
    toastMessage.innerHTML = message;
    toast.style.display = BLOCK;
    
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        cloaseToast();
    }, ALERT_DURATION);
}

function cloaseToast() {
    let toast = document.getElementById(TOAST_ID);
    toast.title = '';
    toast.style.display = NONE;
}

function showCookiesAlertIfRequired() {
    // check to see if cookies were accepted
    let cookiesStatus = getElement(COOKIES_ACCEPTED_KEY);
    if (!isValueEmpty(cookiesStatus)) {
        return;
    }
    let bottomAlert = document.getElementById(BOTTOM_ALLERT_ID);
    bottomAlert.innerHTML = getCookiesMessage();
    bottomAlert.style.display = BLOCK;
}

function acceptCookies() {
    setElement(true, COOKIES_ACCEPTED_KEY);
    let bottomAlert = document.getElementById(BOTTOM_ALLERT_ID);
    bottomAlert.innerHTML = '';
    bottomAlert.style.display = NONE;
}

function getCookiesMessage() {
    return `
    <div class="acceptCoockiesAlert">
        <div class="bottomAlertText">
            ${getStr('acceptCookiesMessage')}
        </div>
        <div class="button" onclick="acceptCookies()">${getStr('accept')}</div>
    </div>
    `;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
<warningLevel>VERBOSE</warningLevel>
```

Not clear exactly why the plugin/compiler processes `scripts.source.js` - seems like `.source.js` is intended to be the initial unchanged source. Maybe just to validate. But if you disable verbose output then the build finishes successfully and the resulting files seem right.